# can't get wiquery to work

Tags: java, javascript, wicket, wiquery

So I can't get wiquery to work, and I'm not sure where to look for what is causing the problem.

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <repository>
        <id>wiquery</id>
        <name>wiquery wicket components</name>
        <url>http://wiquery.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
    </repository>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.odlabs.wiquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiquery-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.odlabs.wiquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiquery-jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Java:

```
    DatePicker<Date> datePicker = new DatePicker<Date>("wiQueryPicker");
    add(datePicker);
```

Html:

```
 <input type="text" wicket:id="wiQueryPicker" />
```

The field appears, but no datepicker is shown when the field gets focus. This is the generated html:

```
 <input type="text" id="wiQueryPickerf4" name="wiQueryPicker" value="" wicket:id="wiQueryPicker">
```

EDIT: In the generated markup, this script is included in the head tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id="wiquery-gen-1324041797627">
 /*<![CDATA[*/
 (function($) {

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wiQueryPicker20c').datepicker({});

 });

 })(jQuery);

 /*]]>*/

 </script>
```

Any suggestions on what's causing the problem?

//Olle

Comment: Does it include the jquery scripts in the header section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my 'main page' I had references to jquery in:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response) {
  response.renderJavaScriptReference(new PackageResourceReference(EyesysMainPanel.class, "javascript/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"));
 }
```

After removing that, wiquery worked properly.